# Output Selected Decision Tree Leaf

Tags: machine-learning, weka, decision-tree

I'm trying to visualize how a decision tree applies to a test set, and I'm using Weka's J48 decision tree.  Weka identifies each sample with a class by evaluating the decision tree and reaching a leaf.  Of course, multiple leaves are tagged with the same class.  Does anybody know how to get Weka to tell, for each sample, which leaf it used to tag that sample?

```
X < 47
|  Y > 10  : Class1 (...)
|  Y <= 10 : Class2 (...)
X >= 47
|  Y > 15  : Class1 (...)
|  Y <= 15
|  |  Z > 10  : Class2 (...)
|  |  Z <= 10 : Class1 (...)
```

I'd like something that would say "sample 15 was classified as Class1 because (X>=47, Y<=15, Z<=10)" or something like that.

Alternatively, I'd like something that says "27 samples were classified as Class1 because (X>=47, Y<=15, Z<=10)".

Alter-alternatively, does anybody know of instances where someone has visualized this info, or of other software that does spit this info out?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd still like a real answer if anyone knows one, but my answer is that Weka does not contain this ability.  My solution is to make a thing that does what I need.  It's available here:

[GitHub:DecisionTreeDNA](https://github.com/kc0bfv/DecisionTreeDNA)

I'm not done with it yet.  It's going to build a cool graph with the numbers, but it already spits out those numbers I wanted.  Oh - the numbers it spits out are of the "27 samples were classified as Class1 because (X>=47, Y<=15, Z<=10)" variety, but it's easy to modify to spit out "sample 15 was classified as Class1 because (X>=47, Y<=15, Z<=10)".